# Is a Workflow associated with list included in list or site template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is a Workflow associated with a list included in list or site template?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a custom workflow, a workflow is deployed in a solution (which can be farm or web application scoped). In the solution there will be a feature which allows you to activate it on a site collection or a site. The association with the list is stored in the workflow through the Association element.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb417439.aspx

Comment: Sorry bad question. What I mean is - if I have a list and create a WF on it and then template the site within SharePoint will the WF be included in the template? Thanks

Comment: I would think so, but why not just try it?